# Request in for loop - scope / responses out of order

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, request

After I perform a request to a .m3u8 Master Playlist Url like https://something.example.com/master.m3u8 with

```
request(input, function (error, response, body) {
  ...
}
```

and after some processing I get back a set of renditions, I store them into an object with some other things prepared, result is like

```
var set = {
    input_url:'https://something.example.com/master.m3u8',
    renditions:[
    {
      id:0,
      url:'https://something.example.com/master_264.m3u8',
      chunks:[]
    },        {
      id:1,
      url:'https://something.example.com/master_578.m3u8',
      chunks:[]
    },        {
      id:2,
      url:'https://something.example.com/master_928.m3u8',
      chunks:[]
    }]
};
```

So I have my set of renditions stored in order from lowest to highest rendition. Now I need to perform another request for each single rendition and store their response into the chunks of each rendition.

**Problem**: After the first callback I get an error message *TypeError: Cannot read property 'chunks' of undefined* - Here is my code

```
for (var i = 0; i < set.renditions.length; i++) {

  var done = false;

  request(set.renditions[i].url, function(error, response, body) {

    set.renditions[i].chunks.push(body);

    completed_requests++;

    if (completed_requests == set.renditions.length) {    

      return callback(null,set);

    }

  });

}
```

I believe this has something to do with a scope ? If am not referencing to original var set within the callback, but push the repsonses to another array, just as they come in, it works, but then they get stored out of order of course. So first the repsonse of 5th rendition, then 3rd rendition, then 4th rendition and so on (as it is an asynch operation) .

Any ideas how I should solve this, maybe something completely different ? Best practice ? Thanks !

=======================

### First Try:

I tried using a forEach, but seems I don't get any result from it ...

```
function chunks (rendition_set, callback) {

var request_complete = false;
var completed_requests = 0

rendition_set.renditions.forEach ( function (entry) {

  request(entry.url, function(error, response, body) {

    var split = body.split('\n');

    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      if (split[i].indexOf('.ts') != -1 ) {
        entry.chunks.push(split[i]);
      }
    }

    completed_requests++;

  }); 

})

while(request_complete == false) {

  if (completed_requests == rendition_set.renditions.length) {

    request_complete = true;
    return callback(null,rendition_set);

  }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) which basically handles all requests for all urls automatically, waits until everything is finished and gives me the result back in one package & **in order** the request was made ... which is pretty neat.

```
async.map(urls, httpGet, function (err, res) {

  if (err) return console.log(err);

  return callback (null, res)

});
```